# CreateDialogIndirectParam crashes on Win 7 64 bit

Tags: winapi, windows-7-x64

I have code which looks something like this.

```
hWnd = CreateDialogIndirectParam(_AtlBaseModule.GetResourceInstance(), pTemplate,
                hWndParent, (DLGPROC)T::StartDialogProc, dwInitParam);
```

This works perfectly fine in a windows XP environment, but the API CreateDialogIndirectParam() seems to crash in a windows 7 64 bit environment.

If we replace the `(DLGPROC)T::StartDialogProc` parameter (where 'T' is a template) with NULL, then the dialog comes up, but it does not have any contents (as expected).

This implies that this parameter is causing the crash.

Any Ideas?

Comment: That's an incredibly unhealthy cast.  Delete (DLGPROC) and fix your code when the compiler complains.

Comment: Looks almost exactly like [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/06/10161590.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If it crashes, then you should be able to check call stack at crash position. It should shed some light on the issue wit the code. CreateDialogIndirectParam API along works well.